# Best practice for making a new index in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to ElasticSearch. I am using it to search variables within market research surveys.

```
survey_id: 100
name: gender
label: Gender
value_labels: {0 => Male, 1 => Female}
```

I have about 400 surveys with around 200000 variables.

I **never** need search for variables for more than one survey at a time.

**Should I be making a new index for each survey, or should I have a field called `survey_id` which I filter on each time I search.?**

What is the best practice here.

Comment: What do you mean by variables here?

Comment: What do you need more? insert or read?

Comment: I definitely would go with a single index and then use a `term` filter on the `survey_id` field.

Comment: @richa Apologies, a variable is one object like in the gray block above.